# how can i handle multiple server MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat

Hi all i am new to spring maven project, and i am using MongoDB. I want to use two tomcats/ MongoDB both of theri IP address are different. when first DB is down i need to connect with second one how it is possible
 I am using following code

```
 public boolean mongoRunningAt(String uri) {
    try {
        Mongo mongo = new Mongo(new MongoURI(uri));
        try {
            Socket socket = mongo.getMongoOptions().socketFactory.createSocket();
            socket.connect(mongo.getAddress().getSocketAddress());
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            mongo = new Mongo(new MongoURI(uri_second));
         Socket socket = mongo.getMongoOptions().socketFactory.createSocket();
            socket.connect(mongo.getAddress().getSocketAddress());
            socket.close();
            //return false;
        }
        mongo.close();
        return true;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Using this code i tried with first one successfully connected, now stoped first DB now restarted server it is connected with second db.

But if i didn't restart server it is always pointing to First only... how should i work on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You deployed 2 servers, are they in a [replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/). If not you can follow the link.
When they are already in a replica set you can use a [connectionstring](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) containing the 2 servers.

Like this:

```
mongodb://db1.example.net,db2.example.net:2500/?replicaSet=test
```

Comment: Hi Hoefmeistert, You are saying me to try with same code instead of UIR "mongodb:127.0.0.1,128.0.0.2:27017" like this?

Comment: When connecting to a replica set you don't need to check if servers are online. Just connect to the replica set. Your server do need to be in a replica set. You need to monitor the replica set yourself (status of the servers). This depends on how en where you are hosting your servers.